# Font bug in Java apps on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, java, fonts, jdk

[image: SOAP UI]

What happens with fonts in my JAVA apps? SOAP UI screen as example (see toolbox)...
I have no idea where is the problem.

SYS: up-to-date ARCH LINUX.

```
$ archlinux-java status
Available Java environments:
java-7-openjdk
java-8-jdk (default)
java-8-jre/jre
java-8-openjdk
```

Comment: Did you recently install new packages? I've had a similar problem when I installed font-config on RHEL because it changes the default OS font (which you can also change). Is the font of your terminals changed as well?

Comment: Simply change the display font of Java should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284296/how-to-configure-jre-to-run-on-specific-font

Comment: Simply change the display font of Java should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284296/how-to-configure-jre-to-run-on-specific-font

Comment: @warl0ck That isn't work. :(

Comment: @Dave Font-config installed. If i drop Font-config it's help? In term i set ubuntu mono manually.

Comment: Also in SQL DEVELOPER font rendering work fine...

Comment: @BrandonFarber did you recently install font-config? (including as a dependency to something else). It may have been what changed your fonts.

Comment: @Dave yes. installed: fontconfig-infinality, freetype2-infinality, lib32-fontconfig. But these packages are installed in an attempt to fix this problem.

Comment: @BrandonFarber if the problem occurred before installing fontconfig I would think it's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution!
first:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Second (add this string to config):

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=setting'
```

But I did't understand something. According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts) article **setting** is not a value. Also above described parameter earlier is not specified at all and this problem been present.

Comment: According to the article you cite, settings is one of off, on, gasp, lcd, lcd_hbgr and a few redundances of the above.

Comment: You're supposed to replace `setting` with one of the listed values; that's why *setting* is in italics in the article you linked. I'm guessing that Java sees `setting` as an invalid value and uses a default one instead, and that default one is what you need to set it to. There aren't too many options so I'd recommend just trying them all